# How to check if a string is translated or not in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, locale

I did a rewrite of this class: `Mage_Core_Model_Translate` and I focus on this function `_getTranslatedString` So I changed it into this:

```
protected function _getTranslatedString($text, $code)
{
    $this->checkTranslatedString($text, $code);
    return parent::_getTranslatedString($text, $code);
}

public function checkTranslatedString($text, $code)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($code, $this->getData()) && !array_key_exists($text, $this->getData())) {
        Mage::log('"'.$text.'",""', null, 'test.log', null);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to check all of the non translated strings for a page. So I would like to have it logged in my `test.log` file. My script seems to check all just the locale folder from my theme, not the `app/locale/de_DE/` files (for instance). 
How I can adapt my script to check those files too ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to compare the strings:

```
protected function _getTranslatedString($text, $code)
{
    $translated = parent::_getTranslatedString($text, $code);
    $this->checkTranslatedString($text, $translated, $code);
    return $translated;
}

public function checkTranslatedString($text, $translated, $code)
{
    if ($text !== $translated) {
        Mage::log('"'.$text.'",""', null, 'test.log', null);
    }
}
```

Comment: will this check also the files from `app/locale` or only just from `app/design/frontend/mytheme/locale` ?  thnx

Comment: Magento uses fallback to verify the strings to translate.
The first string founded is returned.
Is this order: 
1º Database, 2º mytheme/locale, 3º app/locale.

You can test removing the string from mytheme/locale